# iOS swift parse push notification , pushes sent 0

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, notifications, push

devices are registered in installation class properly ( i guess), when i send a push notification from parse website , the status is green tick however pushes sent is 0 , here is my code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.e

    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

    // Initialize Parse.
    Parse.setApplicationId("xxxxxx",
        clientKey: "xxxxxx")


    // [Optional] Track statistics around application opens.
    PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)

    PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)

    var defaultACL = PFACL()
    defaultACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true)
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true)
    PFACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, withAccessForCurrentUser: true)


    let userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationType.Alert |  UIUserNotificationType.Badge |  UIUserNotificationType.Sound);

    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.Background {
        // Track an app open here if we launch with a push, unless
        // "content_available" was used to trigger a background push (introduced
        // in iOS 7). In that case, we skip tracking here to avoid double
        // counting the app-open.
        let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.respondsToSelector(Selector("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:"))
        let noPushPayload: AnyObject? = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]
        if oldPushHandlerOnly || noPushPayload != nil {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
        }
    }

    return true
}
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    if application.applicationState == .Inactive  {
        // The application was just brought from the background to the foreground,
        // so we consider the app as having been "opened by a push notification."
        PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
    }
}
func application(application: UIApplication,  didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],  fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if application.applicationState == .Inactive {
        PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    // Store the deviceToken in the current Installation and save it to Parse
    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    installation.saveInBackground()
}
```

when a user sign up :

```
 let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
                installation["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
                installation["username"] = self.userName.text.lowercaseString
                installation.saveInBackground()
```

sending push :

```
let pushQuery = PFInstallation.query()
        pushQuery!.whereKey("username", equalTo:"\(self.childName)") // Set channel

        // Send push notification to query
        let push = PFPush()
        push.setQuery(pushQuery) // Set our Installation query
        push.setMessage("\(self.parentName) adopted you, you earned $\(self.configureText(10 * childValue / 100)) !")

        push.sendPushInBackground()
```

Comment: Sometimes you need to refresh certificates on Parse site.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to send push notifications through the Parse website? If not, then you are missing some certificates.

This all looks good assuming that self.childname contains the correct recipient username. Have you made sure to enable client pushes?

By default, you cannot send pushes directly from the mobile app, so you will have to enable this feature for your code to work.
[Parse iOS Push Notifications Tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications)